# PhpStorm shortcut to generate constructor params functionality

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a shortcut in PhpStorm to generate code for `$model2` same as `$model1`?

```
class Test{    
    private $model1;
    public function __construct(string $model1, $model2)
    {
       $this->model1 = $model1;
       ....          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Place caret on `__construct` or inside its' parameters .. and invoke Quick Fix menu (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> or via light bulb icon).
2. Choose appropriate option there -- it will be `Initialize fields`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, place cursor on `$model2`, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose option `Initialize fields`.

It will create a private field in your class (if it doesn't exists yet), and assign it inside constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize and create __construct method by shortcut

Place your cursor where you want to create __construct method then press ALT + Insert
[Select constructor and choose your propertise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKJJz.jpg)